# android - how to define touchable areas inside a circle

Tags: android, button, opengl-es, android-canvas, geometry

I'm currently trying to create a circle (via canvas drawing, opengl or drawable) and define 4-5 buttons inside of it. My first thought was to create some drawables (quarters of circles) and overlay them onto the main circle, but then I'll have the touchable zone too large - e.g. in the middle of the main circle.

Is there anyone who tried this and found a decent solution to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just override `onTouch()` in your custom `View` that draws the circle (and other button graphics), and do a bit of simple maths when you get the finger down event to determine whether the user has touched within the circle, and what particular defined zone within the circle.

Comment: Thought of this also, but I was hoping I could find a more elegant solution to this because I also want to highlight those buttons after they were clicked.

Comment: marked as the correct answer, as I can't find another solution.